ALC269VB - нестабильная работа звука linux
Получил ноутбук на i5 1240p.
Нестабильно работает звук. Очень тихий и с шумами, под windows такого не было.
За звук отвечает PCH [HDA Intel PCH], устройство 0: ALC269VB Analog [ALC269VB Analog]
Я пробовал по статье на хабр действовать, но только со своими параметрами аудио.

не помогло.

Так же пробовал с установкой alsa-tools-gui как советовали тут, с перераспределением звука - не помогло.
Что бы было наглядно, о чем я говорю:
Нестабильная работа звука Red OS
Стабильная работа звука Windows 11
Сейчас стоит ubuntu 24.04.1 с ядром 6.8.0-50-generic
